# Smarty, a total value not possible

Tags: php, count, smarty

with Smarty variable `[{$ getCnt | var_dump}]` I have the following values:

`int (3) int (1) int (1)`

But now I want to have the total value. That is, in this example: 5

PHP:

How can I objects in a variable counting?

I get that at in PHP with `var_dump ($ getCnt)`.

`object (selections) # 214 (4) {values​​}`
`object (selections) # 215 (4) {values​​}`
`object (selections) # 216 (4) {values​​}`
`object (selections) # 217 (4) {values​​}`
`object (selections) # 218 (4) {values​​}`

There are total of 5 objects. How can I using PHP Find out how many objects has a variable?

Advance thank you!

Comment: "how many objects has a variable?" ..so the variable is an array of objects then, isn't it? If so, you can simple `count($getCnt)` or in smarty `{$getCnt|count}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use {$getCnt|array_sum} using php function in smarty like this and get the total of array where $getCnt need to be array

check my code here

```
<?php
  $array=array(3,2,1);
  $smarty->assign('test',$array);
  $smarty->display('test.tpl');
?>
```

and in test.tpl

```
{$test|array_sum}
```

am using Smarty-3.1.12

Comment: what version of smarty are you using ?

Comment: My question I have Updated, see above.

Comment: please give the entire objects ,it confusing

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Smarty before so I'm not familiar with its syntax, but PHP has a built in `array_sum()` method which calculates the sum of the values stored within an array. Assuming `$ getCnt` is a variable:

```
$total = array_sum($getCnt);
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php